# I want my object to move both forward and to the right if condition is true (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So right now I have an object that when the mouse is clicked I want to move forward and to the left or forward and to the right. This would create forward diagonal motion.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        if (dir == Vector3.forward) {
            dir = Vector3.left && Vector3.forward;
        } else {
            dir = Vector3.right && Vector3.forward;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about using `new Vector3(float x, float y, float z)`?

Comment: Did you mean to use a bitwise AND: [&](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector3.left` is short-hand for `Vector3(-1, 0, 0)` and `Vector3.forward` shorthand for `Vector3(0, 0, 1)`. So you could instead make a `Vector3` using it's constructor [`Vector3(float x, float y, float z)`] to combine those:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   if(dir.Equals(new Vector3(1, 0, 1))) {
        dir = new Vector3(-1, 0, 1);
   } else {
        dir = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: My object is starting from a zero position (it is not moving), when I try this method on the 2nd click it keeps travelling in the initial (-1,0,1) direction. How do I basically make it move in a zig zag direction after in begins moving.

Comment: That's because `dir == Vector3.forward` will never be true if only this event is getting triggered. You could change it to be based on the value it's set in the `else`, such as `if(dir.Equals(Vector3(1, 0, 1)))` or use a Boolean flag.

Comment: So would that look like

`if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
 if (dir == (Vector3.forward(1, 0 , 1))) {
dir = new Vector3(-1, 0, 1);
} else {
dir = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
}
}`

Comment: @Trlewi I've modified the question to show what it would look like.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this better, it looks like the code is saying when the mouse is tapped if the player is moving diagonally the right move the player diagonally to the left, else move the player diagonally to the right.

Comment: Also because of the '`dir.Equals...` do I no longer need the == operator?

Comment: @Trlewi You can use `==` here, but `Equals` is more accurate for close floating point values. So I generally recommend using it because of that. Also yes that's what the code is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @SpencerWieczorek thank you for your help, I fixed a small error in what you provided and now it's working just fine.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   if(dir == new Vector3(1, 0, 1)) {
      dir = new Vector3(-1, 0, 1);
   } else {
      dir = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
   }
}
```

Again thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I was trying to pair operators but using the points makes sense. Easier to alter moving forward as well and allows for more control.

Comment: If [spencer's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43485842/3785314)  solution worked, you can just accept it as answer instead of leaving your own answer.....

Comment: I've selected Spencer's solution as the answer but just wanted to let anyone else know that it didn't work until I fixed the error. But thank you.

Comment: If you look at the second line of code you wrote `if(dir.Equals(Vector3....`
but when I put this in it kept giving an error and wouldn't run, not sure whey but when I changed it to `if(dir == new Vector3...)` it worked. Not sure why the changing the syntax fixed it but it works now so thank you!

Comment: Try `dir.Equals(new Vector3(..))`instead with `new` added. I'd assume you wouldn't need to create a new instance every time you need to check a Vector but I didn't have Unity up so I may of been wrong. **Edit**: Just checked, yeah the `new` was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Vectors together to get what you want.

```
if (dir == Vector3.forward) {
    dir = Vector3.left + Vector3.forward;
} else {
    dir = Vector3.right + Vector3.forward;
}
```

Check out the [Vector3 page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) on the Unity docs and scroll down to see a list of operators you can use like +, - and *.

Comment: This is the same thing where the object just moves forever in the forward+right direction.

Comment: that depends on whatever dir is prior to the condition. If you want it to move forward+left then dir should be set to forward.